# Keeping sections DRY with Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there a way with Razor to keep sections DRY?

In a parent view:

```
@RenderSection("Foo")

More content..

@RenderSection("Foo")
```

In a child view:

```
@section {
   <text>bar</text>
}
```

I get errors when I try to have 2 sections with the same name.

Comment: You can render partial views (the same view) in each of the uniquely-named sections.

Comment: True, but its just a one liner in there.

Answer (score 0):

[RenderSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg547830%28v=vs.99%29) is a method with a return value (so it doesn't directly write to the `Response`). Store the value in a variable and use it everywhere you want:

Something like:

```
@{ var fooSection = RenderSection("Foo").ToHtmlString(); }

@Html.Raw(fooSection)

More content..

@Html.Raw(fooSection)
```